# Nginx redirect to URL with #

Tags: nginx, url

I want e.g. `https://example.com/to/redirect` be redirected by nginx to `https://example.com/some/url/with/#my-beautiful-id`. However, in nginx config files `#` is used for comments

Is it possible? What should I write to the nginx config so it will work?

### Does not work

```
server {
    ...
    location /to/redirect {
        ...
        return https://example.com/some/url/with/%23my-beautiful-id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your HTTP return code? The `#` character won't be treated as start of the comment if you use it like `return 301 /some/url/with/#my-beautiful-id;`

Comment: I didn't know that it's not treated as a comment, that's helpful! As per not including the HTTP code, it can be omitted if the code is 302 as per the documentation (3rd form) here https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return

Comment: Hm, didn't know that the code can be omitted at all. However for that case documentation states: *Such a parameter should start with the `http://`, `https://`, or `$scheme` string.*

Comment: Oh, sorry, in my actual config it does so I assumed it worked that way even like this. I will edit the answer accordingly. It has indeed worked. I thought it was a comment since my IDE colored it as one. Would you write it as a quick answer please so I can credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` character is not processed as start of the comment being a part of some string, e.g. `https://example.com/some/url/with/#my-beautiful-id`. However it **is** processed as start of the comment being prepended with space, `{`, `}` or `;` characters (not sure this is a full list). To prevent it from being processed that way you need to quote your strings:

```
set $test 123#456;     # $test variable value is '123#456'
set $test 123;#456;    # $test variable value is '123', #456 treated as the comment
set $test "123;#456";  # $test variable value is '123;#456'
set $test '123;#456';  # $test variable value is '123;#456'
```

Usually there is no need to quote the string in nginx config (unless it contains a space or some other special character like `{`, `}` etc.), but you are always free to do it, meaning the lines

```
return https://example.com/some/url/with/#my-beautiful-id;
```

and

```
return "https://example.com/some/url/with/#my-beautiful-id";
```

are completely equal.